# How do I call the API with Axios on the (child) component and present the result on the Page (parent) component in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component, nuxt.js

[image]

If I run this code on the Page component (`mountains.vue`) it works and I get the data from the API with help with Axios:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(mountain, index) in mountains" :key="index">
        {{ mountain.title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mountains: [],
    };
  },
  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const mountains = await $axios.$get("https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains");
    return { mountains };
  },
};
</script>
```

But I want to put this code in a component (`MountainsList`) and do the Axios call in the component (`MountainsList`), but display the data on the Page component (`mountains.vue`) by injecting the component in Nuxt like this:

```
<template>
  <MountainsList />
</template>
```

Now when I run the code, the data using Axios doesn't appear anymore... So how do I inject the data to the Page component above doing the Axios call in the child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asyncData` only works on a page

From the docs

> asyncData is called every time before loading the **page** component

One way you can accomplish what you want is passing the mountains in as a prop to the `MountainList` component. Something like below...

```
<template>
  <MountainList :mountains="mountains" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const mountains = await $axios.$get("https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains");
    return { mountains };
  },
};
</script>
```

And the component with the code and prop mountains...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(mountain, index) of mountains" :key="index">
        {{ mountain.title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
  props: ['mountains'],
};
</script>
```

If you really want to make the API call in the child component you can use the [fetch](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch) method.

Also you should not define a `data()` property on the page. I believe it will overwrite the server rendered data.

Answer (score 1):

According to [official docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure#the-components-directory) :

> Components in this directory will not have access to [`asyncData`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data).

It means that any components inside the `components` folder cannot access that method.